# Login with completely different template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is possible to create a login page with a html completely different of main html in angular2? If possible, how?

### **UPDATE**

My app template currently is:

```html
<div class="loading"></div>
<header></header>
<section id="main">
    ...
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    ...
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

This is the common html for all my components, except login.

The login component have a completely different html but i dont know how to introduce it here hidding the loading, header, section and footer.

I did it inserting another `<router-outlet>` at end and I controlling both routers with ng-if but I dont know if this is a good practice

Any clue?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you try to accomplish. For me it's quite unclear what you want to know. What have you tried? Where did you fail?

Comment: I was searching for its, the best I could find is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2/38783451#38783451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch layouts in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2)