# Render multiple router-outlets in Angular 2 app.component

Tags: angular

I have my angular component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-app',
  template: `
        <div *ngIf="isEmptyLayout">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="!isEmptyLayout">
            <h1>Not empty template</h1>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { ...
```

What I want to do is create separated layout for landing page and admin area. However, this renders an error. What are your suggestions to render router-outlet few times depending on current url?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Multiple layout in angular 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2/38783451#38783451)

Hope it helps. Been using it for a while now and it scales very well no matter the number of layout your would want to use in your app

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use multiple router outlets? You could structure your template like this:

```
<div>
    <h1 *ngIf="!isEmptyLayout">Not empty template</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```