# Angular Routing: Replacing components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am doing a project for my own learning and stuck on this simple problem.
I have first/main page as login/register page. Now I want to replace page with other component using routing. As I click register I want to see only register-form component. I have module ENTRY with its own entry.routing, there are three components login component, register component and register-form component. On first page I am viewing login and register components, their directives are in app component's html to view them. How do I change form app.component to register-form.component in view?

Here is some of my code:

app.component.html

```
<div class="flex-row">
<div class="flex-grow-one logo">
    <h1>Something</h1>
</div>
<div class="flex-column flex-grow-one entry-section">
    <app-login></app-login>
    <div class="separation"></div>
    <app-register></app-register>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EntryModule } from './modules/entry/entry.module';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EntryModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

entry.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterFormComponent } from './components/register-form/register-form.component';

const entryRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register-form', component: RegisterFormComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      entryRoutes
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class EntryRouting {}
export const EntryRoutingComponents = [
  RegisterFormComponent
];
```

register.component.html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">
    <h2>REGISTER</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-form">
      <div class="card-input">
        <input type="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-input">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      </div>
      <div class="card-actions">
        <button routerLink="/register-form" class="button-register">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know there must be a router-outlet, but I don't really know where to put it, because if I put it inside register.component.html, it shows register-form component on the same view, where the router-outlet is.

Comment: i dont see your `EntryRouting` in app.module.ts `imports`

Comment: @Avinash yes. I have another module entry.module, where entry.routing is imported. So as I am importing EntryModule into AppModule, I think it should work. And it works, it just doesn't do what I need it to do. :)

Comment: If i am not wrong you are having login, register components in the home path and trying to replace that entire view with registerForm, then you need to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html and define your routes accordingly
[have a look at this, this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2/38783451#38783451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a routing module where you define url and its child urls. In the module, make a parent component for the registercomponent. Let's say your home url is /home which is controlled by the Rootcomponent, it display the header and footer and some content in the middle. so the html of the root component might look like:

```
<div>some header info</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>some footer info</div>
```

The route module should look like:

    `const appRoute : Routes = [{
        path: '/home',
            component: RootComponent,
            children: [
            {
              path: '/login',
              component: AppComponent,
            },
            {
              path: '/registration',
              component: RegisterComponent,
            }
           ]
       }
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class myRouteModule {};`

Inject the module into your root module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RootComponent,
    AppComponent,
    registerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    myRoutModule
   ]
})
```

The middle content of the page is dynamically controlled by the current routing. If the url is /home/login, then the app view will be shown. For /home/registration, the register component will be shown instead.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! As I am reading deeper into routing, I think your suggestion might be the right one. I will try this tomorrow and will report if it works.

Comment: Hi, where is the Registration-Form Component that needs to be finally displayed? And which one is myRouteModule?

Comment: Hi Anish, myRouteModule is the name of the self-defined app routing module. By exporting it, other Angular module can import the routing module. For details, refer to  https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules.